# LibreOffice 5.0 showing greek letters in place of the for the application interface

Tags: encoding, settings, fedora, libreoffice

I'm new to Linux and I'm using Fedora 14 currently. 
The LibreOffice5.0 user interface is showing greek letters in place of the normal English interface. I tried to change it from Tools > Options > Language settings (although its not shown in English) but nothing was happening.I tried to reed the Greek symbols and found they are exactly the same translation of the English letters (Like A- alpha).

Please find the screenshot

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeboZ.png)

Comment: Fedora 14 is EOL for many years. You should install something more recent.

Comment: I'm helpless, its my office PC.

Comment: Please ask your office IT people to upgrade.

Comment: there are compatibility issues with some software tools, so cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14 shipped with OpenOffice.org version 3.3.0. It looks like you have a recent version of LibreOffice from some other source else. This is an unsupported configuration in any case, but mixing and matching current and *that* old (2011) is particularly asking for trouble.

It might be possible to mess with fonts and font configuration to address this particular problem, but odds are that there are others lurking underneath. (And that's not even considering security concerns.)

I highly recommend upgrading to Fedora Workstation 23. LibreOffice 5 is included, and it should work "out of the box".

(Disclaimer: I work on Fedora.)

Comment: Thank you for your replay,  I was using  OpenOffice.org version 3.3.0 when it started showing this problem i installed LibreOffice 5, thinking this might solve my problem. But the problem remained.